# databricks dataframe to oracle Db using JDBC creates string column with varchar(255) only while string values are larger than 255. how to fix this?

Tags: python, oracle, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using below python command to write the dataframe to Oracle Db and MS SQL Db. This dataframe has schema generated out of the values, and that includes string type fields/columns by datatype. Some of the values are very larger like around size of 750 or above.

The below one to MS SQL creates the string type fields as varchar(max) by default and hence no issues.

```sql
usersDF.write \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", conn)\
  .option("user", sqlUserName)\
  .option("password", dbPassword)\
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")\
  .option("dbTable", "DBS_Processed_Users") \
  .mode('overwrite')\
  .save()
```

Whereas, the same when attempted against Oracle db, creates the string type fields as varchar(255) by default.

```sql
usersDF.write \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", oraConn)\
  .option("user", oraUserName)\
  .option("password", oraPassword)\
  .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")\
  .option("dbTable", "Schema.DBS_Processed_Users") \
  .mode('overwrite')\
  .save()
```

What's the best way to ensure that the write to Oracle gets created with max or 1000 as precision? I can even create the table but the mode=overwrite, somehow overwrites it to 255 and causing the data write failures.

Is there any better recommendations to this problem or any solutions?

Comment: Have you looked at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508905/pyspark-dataframe-write-jdbc-to-dynamic-creation-of-table-with-given-schema

Comment: Thanks @teedak8s for your response. I tried with the option below then, but its giving me an error "parse Exception", ```usersDF.write \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", oraConn)\
  .option("user", oraUserName)\
  .option("password", oraPassword)\
  .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")\
  ***.option("createTableColumnTypes", "persontext VARCHAR2(1024), matchingReason varchar2(500)")*** \
  .option("dbTable", "Schema.DBS_Processed_Users") \
  .mode('overwrite')\
  .save()```. What is going wrong here? should i use a diferent mechanism for writing to Db?